# Pressing 'Enter' to confirm refresh in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, if I have posted a page and I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh, I see the 'Confirm Form Resubmission' window as I would expect.

[image: Confirm Form Resubmission]

However, it's acting somewhat strange. For a start (this is how I noticed), I cannot press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on my keyboard to confirm, which I'm sure I used to be able to do. When playing around a bit, I noticed that I can't actually grab the dialog box and drag it around like I would expect (think JavaScript alert boxes). I can click the cross, and both the buttons, so it is still working (not crashed) but just very strangely.

Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: could you tell us in what site that happens ?

Comment: I'm working on a local development site in case that makes a difference, not sure it should though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tab-related dialogs are actually managed by Chrome, not OS, and there are some good reasons for that.

Imagine a malicious site that shows a hundred of popups one after another. "Classic" OS-managed popups (like for example those in IE6) would completely lock the browser until you close them all, because if a popup is visible, nothing in the main app window can be clicked.

This was solved by a *"Don't show dialogs from this site anymore"* checkbox, but Chrome-managed popups are even better for the second reason: with such popup, you can still switch to another tab and when you're back to the first one, the popup will still be there.

I think guys behind Chrome have realized that making it look like a dialog is a poor design concept, because in Chrome 29 (currently in dev channel) those popups look like this:

[image: POST data refresh popup in Chrome 29 (Polish, dev channel, build 1541)]

Also, <kbd>Enter</kbd> works for confirmation. Changes from dev channel are usually moved to the stable release in 6 to 12 weeks.

If you need a quick fix just for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> thing, Chrome 28 from beta channel already has it sorted out. You can switch to the beta channel [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?extra=betachannel). Of course it's beta so it can be unstable, but from my experience betas are pretty good for everyday use. Some more details about different release channels can be found [here](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).

Comment: So just to confirm, are you saying the experience I am having is to be expected, I shouldn't be able to press `Enter`, at least not at the moment?

Comment: I've just checked Chrome 27 (current stable) on my PC and it has the same issue. It's a bug and it's already fixed in Chrome 28, I'll add a download link in a moment.

Comment: That's wonderful, thank you very much for your help.